# Angular/Typescript numeral.js

Tags: angular, typescript, number-formatting, numeral.js

I want to format a number to also display the Romanian format for decimals and thousands like this: 1.000,23 . I am using the `numeral.js` library.

**Here is my pipe code:**

```
constructor(private session: SessionService) {
    numeral.register('locale', 'ro', {
        delimiters: {
            thousands: this.session.Settings.groupSymbols,
            decimal: this.session.Settings.decimalSymbols
        },
        abbreviations: {
            thousand: 'k',
            million: 'm',
            billion: 'b',
            trillion: 't'
        },
        ordinal: function (number) {
            return number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème';
        },
        currency: {
            symbol: 'RON'
        }
    });
    numeral.locale("ro");
}

public transform(value: string) {
    var b = numeral(value);
    var x = "0,0.";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.session.Settings.decimalDigits; i++) {
        x = x + "0";
    }

    return b.format(x);
}
```

**This is the tags output displayed:**

```
<label>{{ '12345678' | decimalUnitPipe }}</label>
<br>
<label>{{ '1.234,5678' | decimalUnitPipe }}</label>
<br>
<label>{{ '1,234.5678' | decimalUnitPipe }}</label>
<br>
<label>{{ '1,2345678' | decimalUnitPipe }}</label>
<br>
<label>{{ '1.2345678' | decimalUnitPipe }}</label>
```

**And this is the output displayed by the browser:**

```
12,345,678.00 
1.23 
1,234.57 
12,345,678.00 
1.23
```

How can I convert my local to display my numbers in the wanted format like in the label? On the first number, it also displays the decimals `(.00)` and I do not want them to be displayed if I do not put any decimals in there. In the second one, it shows `1.23` and I want it to show `1.234,5678` etc.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this locale. Can you provide a list of inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: input 12,345,678.00 -> output 12,345,678   input 1.23 -> output 1,234.5678
1,234.57 
input 12,345,678.00 -> output 1,2345678
input 1.23 -> output 1.2345678

Comment: have you tried delimiters: {
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ','
}